# Rubymine can't load file projects after running git clean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, rubymine

I have added some files to `.gitignore`, then run the command `git clean -options` to clean some untracked files. (Sorry, I don't remember what options I used). Then, Rubymine can't load all files in my projects. I open the project source tree, and all I can see are the following files `.gitignore, Gemfile, Gemfile.lock, Readme.md, and some other unimportant files`. I think the problem occurs because of the git command I use above. I am wondering if anybody has faced this problem before. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check this, hope this may save you

`git reflog` it is explained here

http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/09/reflog-your-safety-net.html

Also remember you can always go back to your previous stable commit `git checkout [revision]` or undoing your changes.

https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/undoing-changes